# How to use Websync in .Net Maui

Tags: rest, maui, publish-subscribe, websync

I've been a long time advocate of FrozenMoutain WebSync (and TheRest) products. Very well built and was working great in our web site and Xamarin app for years.  We are now in the process of converting our apps from Xamarin Forms to .Net Maui and wish to keep our WebSync components in place in our apps, but we get errors from the components.

Here is the error stack:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'.
   at System.Net.HttpWebResponse.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.HttpWebResponse.get_StatusCode()
   at FM.HttpWebRequestTransfer.ProcessBinaryResponse(HttpWebResponse response, HttpRequestArgs requestArgs)
   at FM.HttpWebRequestTransfer.SendBinary(HttpRequestArgs requestArgs)
   at FM.HttpWebRequestTransfer.SendText(HttpRequestArgs requestArgs)
   at FM.HttpTransfer.Send(HttpRequestArgs requestArgs)
```

I tried reaching out to FrozenMountain but they are not of any help anymore (they discontinued those products for a higher-scale, more expensive product that I can't afford). Any one else went over this problem and found a solution by any luck? I wish I can find a work around before looking for alternative solutions, which would require important application and server-side architecture changes. Thanks!